# Piece to hot air balloon won't fit. Anything I can do?

Tags: friends

I am putting together the [41097 hot air balloon](http://brickset.com/sets/41097-1/Heartlake-Hot-Air-Balloon) with my daughter and there is a red piece that shows a rod should go through however the rod will not go through no matter what we do. There seems to be a stop inside the red piece.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.StackExchange.com! Can you add a picture of either the instruction that doesn't work, or ideally of both the instruction step as well as your actual build? That way we can help you and don't have to guess as to where the issue might be.

Answer (score 11):

My son had the exact same problem with this set at Christmas.
[image]

In step 1, you put the red joiner on the axle. In step 2, there is a smaller axle that gets put in the other end. The only clue is that each step shows what parts are needed, so you can see that there is a little axle there that needs to be incorporated.